# Conjecture on OEIS A167055

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

OEIS [A167055](http://oeis.org/A167055) Numbers n such that $12n + 5$ is prime.

$0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 14, 16, 19, 21,...$ are items of  OEIS A167055.
I conjecture that the set of the sum of every two items of this sequence is the set of nonnegative integers. i.e.:$0+0=0,\ 0+1=1,\ ...,\ 1+4=5,...$

Further information for A167055 not in OEIS A167055: nonnegative integers  that not of the following two forms:
$$
\begin{align*} 
&3x^2+(6y−3)x−y\\ 
&3x^2+(6y−3)x+(y−1) ,\ x,y \in \mathbb{Z^+}
\end{align*}
$$

Is there some clue to solve this problem?

More information see: [How come if  i  not of the following form, then 12i+5 must be prime?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/775648/how-come-if-i-not-of-the-following-form-then-12i-5-must-be-prime)

Comment: How high have you not disproved the conjecture?

Comment: @PaulPlummer ,I check up to A167055(400),it's amazing.

Comment: @BenjaminDickman , OK,I check to $A167055(2832)$,no problem.

Comment: $A167055(2832) = 9999$, May be some numbers will list at output such as $ 19954, 19959, 19963, 19965, 19966$,you bet if you check up to $A167055(3000)$,all these $ 19954, 19959, 19963, 19965, 19966$ will disappear and so on.

Comment: Also posted to MO, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/167504/conjecture-on-oeis-a167055 --- miket, **you** should have mentioned this.

Comment: @BenjaminDickman what is the heuristic you have in mind? I believe this is heuristically *true* (at least asymptotically) just like Golbach; see my answer on MO.

Comment: @GerryMyerson ,Thanks for the link

Comment: @quid ,Thanks for your answer and edit,related question see: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/779054/are-there-infinitely-many-nonnegative-integers-not-of-the-following-four-forms

Comment: @quid After reading your MO answer, I have deleted my comment; I will not be venturing any further guesses about something that looks like GC...

Comment: @EmilJeřábek ,I dont know if that a number that cannot be expressed like this must be a square.